# Resolve not resolved before loading controller

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to fetch the value from server side before any controller loads. I am using resolvers to achieve this. Since fetched value needs to be visible to all controllers I extended routeConfig on the following way:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp', [.....]).

config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {

    var universalResolves = {

        user: function(User, $q, $rootScope) {
            var deffered = $q.defer();

            User.query({},
                function (users) {
                    deffered.resolve(
                        $rootScope.activeUser = users[0]
                    )
                }, function(){
                    deffered.reject();
                }
            );

            return deffered.$promise;
        }


    };

    var customRouteProvider = angular.extend({}, $routeProvider, {
        when: function(path, route) {
            route.resolve = (route.resolve) ? route.resolve : {};
            angular.extend(route.resolve, universalResolves);
            $routeProvider.when(path, route);
            return this;
        }
    });

    customRouteProvider.when('/users', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/users.html',
        controller: 'UserController'
    });

    customRouteProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/home'});
}]);
```

But when I try to print activeUser from the controller I am getting 'undefined'.

```
.controller('UserController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

        console.log($scope.activeUser.id);
        .....

 };
```

Here I am getting the following error:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined.

Why the value is not resolved before loading controller?

Comment: $scope.activeEnvironment is never assigned...

Comment: I am sorry, I edited the code. I needed to rewrite the code, since I am not allowed to share it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such property `$promise` of deferred object, it is `promise`:

```
user: function(User, $q, $rootScope) {
    var deffered = $q.defer();

    User.query({}, function(users) {
        deffered.resolve($rootScope.activeUser = users[0]);
    }, function() {
        deffered.reject();
    });

    return deffered.promise;
    //             ^ don't put $ here
}
```

Also it's better to inject resolved `user` to controller then using $rootScope:

```
.controller('UserController', ['$scope', 'user', function ($scope, activeUser) {
    console.log(activeUser.id);
};
```

An finally just for better codding style, this assignment

```
$rootScope.activeUser = users[0]
```

is a little confusing. It's more readable:

```
$rootScope.activeUser = users[0];
deffered.resolve(users[0]);
```